# Extending abelian schemes and their polarizations from an open subset

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-schemes

Let $S$ be a smooth quasi-projective scheme over $\mathbb{Z}$, and $A$ an abelian scheme over an open subset $U \subset S$. Suppose that $S\backslash U$ has codimension at least $2$ and that for every point $s \in S$, the ramification index at the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{S,s}$ is $1$, so that the hypotheses for the Faltings-Chai and Vasiu-Zink criteria hold at each stalk.
Then

1. Can $A$ be extended to an abelian scheme over $S$?
2. If $A$ comes equipped with a principal polarization $\lambda$, and $A$ extends to an abelian scheme $B$ over $S$, can we extend $\lambda$ to a principal polarization on $B$?

Take a generic point $\eta$ of an irreducible component of $S \backslash U$. The stalk $\mathcal{O}_{S,\eta}$ has a map $f:\textrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{S,\eta}) \to S$ and we have an abelian scheme $f^*A$ defined outside the maximal point of $\mathcal{O}_{S,\eta}$. We are in a position to apply either Faltings-Chai or Vasiu-Zink to extend $f^*A$ uniquely to an abelian scheme $A'_{\eta}$ over the stalk. We can then spread this out to an abelian scheme $A'_{U_{\eta}}$ over some open $U_{\eta}$ containing $\eta$.

For any other point $\zeta$ so that $\eta \in \overline{\zeta}$, we know $\zeta \in U \cap U_{\eta}$ and if $g: \textrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{S,\zeta}) \to S$ is the natural map then $g^*A \cong g^*A'_{U_{\eta}}$ (abusing notation slightly). We can spread this out to an isomorphism of abelian schemes $g_{\zeta} : A |_{W_{\zeta}} \to A'_{U_{\eta}}|_{W_{\zeta}}$ over some open $W_{\zeta}$ around $\zeta$.

As long as the cocycle conditions are satisfied, we would be able to glue $A$ and $A_{U_{\eta}}'$, after potentially shrinking $U_{\eta}$, to an abelian scheme over a strictly larger open $U \cup U_{\eta}$. The logic behind the previous paragraph ensures that $\eta$ remains in $U_{\eta}$ after shrinking. Now a Zorn's lemma type argument allows us to conclude (1).

The cocycle conditions hold at least generically (after taking generic fibre above $S$), so by rigidity of abelian schemes, I suspect that they hold, and the question (1) is indeed true.

As for (2), the line bundle $L$ on $A$ which induces the principal polarization can be extended over $B$ to some $\overline{L}$, and we obtain a morphism $\phi_{\overline{L}}:B \to B^{\vee}$. I suspect that relative ampleness can be verified pointwise on $S$, and supposing that $\overline{L}$ is a polarization, it must be principal since it is so generically.

Comment: I do not understand your argument above.  Are you asking whether or not you can check "extendability" as a condition over the Spec of stalks of the structure sheaf of $S$?  The answer to that is "yes", and that is what the Faltings-Chai and Vasiu-Zink results are about.  However, you seem to be asking whether "extendability" always holds, even without assuming extendability over Spec of stalks of the structure sheaf, and the answer to that is "no."

Comment: @JasonStarr Suppose that the hypotheses for Faltings-Chai and Vasiu-Zink hold at all stalks of the structure sheaf of $S$ (I.E. $S\backslash U$ has codimension $\geq 2$ and the indices of ramification at all stalks are $1$). Then does 'extendability' hold? Alternatively, if for any prime $p \in spec(\mathbb{Z})$, the fiber $A_{(p)} \to U_{(p)}$ above $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ can be extended to an abelian scheme over all of $S_{(p)}$, does "extendability" hold?

Comment: @JasonStarr But you are right, I want to know if Faltings-Chai and Vasiu-Zink have any global implications, about abelian schemes over nice schemes over $\mathbb{Z}$, as opposed to $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a general outline. We can even extend over codimension $1$ points if we can verify good reduction.

$\textbf{Proposition}:$
Let $U \subset S$ be an open subset of a smooth scheme over $\mathbb{Z}$, with complement of codimension at least $2$. Let $A_U$ be an abelian scheme over $U$. Then $A_U$ extends to an abelian scheme $A$ over $S$.

$\textit{proof}:$
Consider the poset of extensions $(U \subset W,A_W)$ of $A_U$. It suffices to show that the maximal element is defined over $S$. Take a maximal element $(U \subset W,A_W)$ and suppose $W \neq S$. Let $\eta \in S \backslash W$ be a generic point of an irreducible component of the complement, and consider the stalk $S_{(\eta)}$. If this local ring is of mixed characteristic, then it is a quasi-healthy local ring, since the ramification index is $1$, and so we are able to use the Vasiu-Zink criterion. If it has residue characteristic $0$, then we are able to use the Faltings-Chai criterion. The conclusion is that since $A_W \big |_{S_{(\eta)}}$ is defined everywhere outside the maximal point, it extends uniquely to an abelian scheme $A_{(\eta)}/ S_{(\eta)}$.

We now proceed to spread $A_{(\eta)}$ out to an abelian scheme $A_V'$ defined over an open neighbourhood $V$ of $\eta$. The next step is to glue this abelian scheme with $A_W$, after possibly shrinking $V$, to a strictly larger abelian scheme.

Let $\zeta$ be the generic point of some closed subscheme of $S$ containing $\overline{\eta}$. Then $\phi_{\zeta}: (A_V')_{(\zeta)} \xrightarrow{\sim} (A_W)_{(\zeta)}$ as abelian schemes over the stalk, and this spreads out to an isomorphism of abelian schemes $\phi_{W'_{\zeta}}$ in some open subset $W'_{\zeta} \subset W \cap V$ which contains $\zeta$. Consider $W' = \cup_{\zeta}W'_{\zeta} \subset W \cap V$. By removing some closed subsets, we can shrink $V$ so that $W \cap V = W'$, and $\eta$ still lies in $V$ since by construction, we cannot have removed any closed subset containing $\eta$.

Now we are in a position to glue to an abelian scheme $A_{V' \cup W}$ over $V' \cup W$ which is strictly larger. We just need to verify the cocycle conditions for $\{\phi_{W'_{\zeta}}\}_{\zeta}$. More precisely, for any $\zeta_1,\zeta_2$ we must verify
$$\phi_{W'_{\zeta_1}} \big |_{W'_{\zeta_1} \cap W'_{\zeta_2}} = \phi_{W'_{\zeta_2}} \big |_{W'_{\zeta_1} \cap W'_{\zeta_2}}$$
If $\eta_S$ is the generic point of $S$, then actually $(\phi_{W'_{\zeta_1}})_{(\eta_S)} = (\phi_{W'_{\zeta_2}})_{(\eta_S)}$, and due to rigidity of abelian schemes, the two maps above are indeed equal. This gives us a contradiction and so in fact $W = S$ as required.

As for (2), the line bundle $L$ on $A$ which induces the principal polarization can be extended over $B$ to some line bundle $L_B$. By the MO post below, the property of being a polarization is open and closed on the base, so $L_B$ is a polarization. Moreover it is principal because the degree of an isogeny of abelian schemes is constant on the base.

[Is a polarization on an abelian scheme an open condition?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243380/is-a-polarization-on-an-abelian-scheme-an-open-condition)